# What's a proper response status code to REST POST request when duplicate is found?

Tags: http, rest, post, restful-architecture, http-response-codes

In my RESTful API client might try to post information that is already in the database, this is not an error, rather something client can ignore, maybe notify the user about already existing dublicate.

Now i'm returning 409 Conflict and already existing object in the response body. I feel that it's incorrect because:

> The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current
>   state of the resource. This code is only allowed in situations where
>   it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and
>   resubmit the request. The response body SHOULD include enough
>   information for the user to recognize the source of the conflict.
>   Ideally, the response entity would include enough information for the
>   user or user agent to fix the problem; however, that might not be
>   possible and is not required.
>   [via restpatterns.org](http://restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes/409_-_Conflict)

and in general, it seems, that 409 is more associated with PUT.

What is the correct response in this case? Could it be 303 See Other and Location header?

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure there is a correct answer. We are returning a 409 with a message that it's a duplicate resource. We also include hypermedia to that resource. It seems you could also use a 400 - Bad Request but that seemed too generic. I could see the 303 also working. I wanted to indicate that there was an error so we went with the 409.